# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id' (Pyrogram)

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Created a command named redeemcode, to ask the user for redeem code as input and storing it as a variable 'code'

heres the code:

```
@bot.on_message(filters.command('redeemcode'))
def redeemcode(bot, message):
    message.reply_text("Send the code to redeem")
    code = bot.get_messages(chatid, message_ids=message.message_id)
```

and I am getting this error

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\Genshin Bot>C:/Python310/python.exe "d:/Genshin Bot/bot.py"
ERROR:pyrogram.dispatcher:'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 242, in handler_worker
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "d:\Genshin Bot\bot.py", line 67, in redeemcode
    code = bot.get_messages(chatid, message_ids=message.message_id)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'
```

The problem is with getting the message id , can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where do you see that `Message.message_id` exists in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that you cannot get replies to a message from the message you as the bot sent, `message.message_id` has been deprecated in favor of `message.id`, to be more consistent with other types, like `chat.id`, `photo.id`, or `video.id`.

See [Pyrogram's v2 Release Notes](https://docs.pyrogram.org/releases/v2.0) for this:

> **Message.message_id becomes Message.id**: For consistency reasons, `Message.message_id` has been renamed to `Message.id`. This makes it a less redundant name and will reflect with all other types that have the `.id` attribute.